Data seems not reactive, possible bug in svelte.dev tutorial?
I am talking about Svelte.dev tutorial.
Basically, everything (after using the solution of course) works fine (handler answers, database answers, new position is added to array of data.todos), just the view does not update when data.todos is mutated within function. Refreshing view brings new data.todos from database and makes everything correct (new data displayed). So seems, data.todos isn't considered reactive? I'd like to understand why to avoid something similar in the future.

I got an answer from Svelte discord community, that automatic migration Svelte4 to 5 causes that issue, and tutorial content was aparrently automatically migrated, hence doesnt work as intended.
